# Who can crouch the shortest?

Tags: overwatch

With the addition of a new hero, and with more on the way, and with the new emotes for sitting or laying down, I started to wonder about this question. Which hero has the shortest crouch in game? Who has the tallest?

Comment: Torbjorn. And likely Reinhardt (who is tall), or D.va (who can not crouch).

Comment: Heroes who can lie down, like Junkrat, might have an advantage, though it would require a special taunt rather than a crouch.

Comment: @Zibbobz You mean like this? https://youtu.be/koCLvUnRkr4?t=4

Comment: @Unionhawk Yes, I was thinking Torbjorn, but then Ana came in.. she seems to get pretty short...

Comment: Do you mean shortest as in the character whose model is shortest while crouching, or the character who has the most height reduced when crouching?

Comment: @MageXy I'm looking for who's model is the shortest while crouching.

Answer (score 1):

Torbjorn can crouch the shortest, because he is the smallest character ingame. But Junkrat can lie down with his emote and so he can crouch smaller than torbjorn!